# Determine galois group $Gal \Big(\frac{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt{-3})}{\mathbb{Q}}\Big)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I've had some hard time determining Galois group  $Gal \Big(\frac{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt{-3})}{\mathbb{Q}}\Big)$ because I didn't know exactly how to compute the order of the elements. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506876/computing-order-of-elements-of-galois-group-gal-big-frac-mathbbq-sqrt3) for the computation of the orders and the order of the group.

However, I'm arriving at two contradictory conclusions. I get that the order of the group is 6 and that all the non-identity elements are of order 2. However, I know this cannot be the case since there are only the diedric group and the cyclic group of order 6 and in both you find elements of order three.

What am I doing wrong?

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 notation & \sqrt[3]{3} & \sqrt{-3} & order \\ \hline
 Id  &  \sqrt[3]{3} & \sqrt{-3} & 1\\ \hline
 & \sqrt[3]{3} & -\sqrt{-3} & 2\\ \hline
 &  \omega \sqrt[3]{3}& \sqrt{-3}& 2\\ \hline
&  \omega \sqrt[3]{3}& -\sqrt{-3}& 2\\ \hline
&  \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{3}& \sqrt{-3}& 2\\ \hline
&  \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{3}& -\sqrt{-3}& 2\\ \hline
\end{array}

I do the computations considering that $\omega = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. So for instance if I compute the order of the isomorphism that sends $\sqrt[3]{3} \mapsto \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{3}$ and $\sqrt{-3} \mapsto -\sqrt{-3}$ I observe that two applications of this isomorphism on $\sqrt{-3}$ will give the identity and for the other element I have the following chain $\sqrt[3]{3} \mapsto \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{3} \mapsto \omega \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{3}$ observing that $\omega^2 \mapsto \omega$.

**Edit**

Let me update the table as I go along:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 notation & \sqrt[3]{3} & \sqrt{-3} & order \\ \hline
 Id  &  \sqrt[3]{3} & \sqrt{-3} & 1\\ \hline
 & \sqrt[3]{3} & -\sqrt{-3} & 2\\ \hline
 &  \omega \sqrt[3]{3}& \sqrt{-3}& 3\\ \hline
&  \omega \sqrt[3]{3}& -\sqrt{-3}& 2\\ \hline
&  \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{3}& \sqrt{-3}& 3\\ \hline
&  \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{3}& -\sqrt{-3}& 2\\ \hline
\end{array}

So I conclude the group is diedric of 6 elements. Thanks everyone.

Comment: To identify where you are going wrong, would you elaborate on "I get that the order of the group is 6 and that all the non-identity elements are of order 2"? How do you come to each of those conclusions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the automorphism $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(\sqrt[3]{3}) = \omega \sqrt[3]{3}$ and $\sigma(\sqrt{-3}) = \sqrt{-3}$ and note that by your expression for $\omega$, then $\sigma(\omega) = \omega$:
$$
\sigma(\omega) = \sigma \left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}\right) = \frac{-1 + \sigma(\sqrt{-3})}{2} = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2} = \omega \, .
$$
Then
$$
\sigma^2(\sqrt[3]{3}) = \sigma(\omega \sqrt[3]{3}) = \sigma(\omega) \sigma(\sqrt[3]{3}) = \omega \sigma(\sqrt[3]{3}) = \omega \omega \sqrt[3]{3} = \omega^2 \sqrt[3]{3} \neq \sqrt[3]{3}
$$
which shows that $\sigma^2 \neq \mathrm{id}$, so $\sigma$ can't have order $2$.

Comment: How do we know $\omega\sqrt[3]{3}$ is even in the field extension? (I mean, it is, but that needs to be shown.)

Comment: @alex.jordan The OP's expression $\omega = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2}$ shows that $\omega \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, even.

Comment: @Rodrigo This OP doesn't understand the difference between the order of a Galois group element and the multiplicative order of a generating element of the field extension. I'm just saying that this issue about $\omega$ should be made explicit to the OP.

Comment: @Rodrigo Quite right, thanks for the correction.  Also, why did you delete your comment?  It was correct, and exactly how I wanted to respond.

Comment: OP has edited the question since I started thinking about how to respond. If my comments need to be disregarded, OK.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be simpler to remark that by definition, $\omega$ is a primitive cubic root of $1$, so that your field $K$ is just the splitting field of the polynomial $X^3 - 3$ ? As such, $K/\mathbf Q$ is normal, with Galois group $G$ isomorphic to the permutation group of the roots, so $G\cong S_3 \cong D_6$, generated by the transposition $\tau:\omega \to \omega^2, \sqrt [3] 3 \to \sqrt [3] 3$ and the 3-cycle $\sigma: \sqrt [3] 3 \to \omega \sqrt [3] 3, \omega \to \omega$ .